# How to display the records in a text file with empty columns in Unix

Tags: unix

I am new to this.
I have a file with morethan 1000 records. Each column is seperated with a delimiter pipe "|".
I would like to see only the records which has empty columns.

Waiting for the Valuable Answer.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Can you please give an example of input and output and what you have tried already? From your question I do not understand what you really need, nor how you need it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have sample file **data** like this:

```
|void|bar
foo|void|bar
foo||bar
foo|void|
```

I have to look for `||`, `|` at the beginning and `|` in the end. This work for me:

```
cat data | grep "^|\|||\||$"
```

Explanation of `grep`:

- `^|` - beginning of line
- `\|` - OR
- `||` - two of them
- `\|` - OR
- `|$` - end of line

**Output:**

```
|void|bar
foo||bar
foo|void|
```

Answer (score 2):

With egrep you can grep for several strings in one time.
You would like to find lines starting with an enmpty colum (^|),
lines with an empty column in the middle (||) and lines
ending witch an empty line (|$).
egrep uses | as an OR delimiter in the grep string, so all | characters above must be escaped by a \ character.
Result:

```
$ cat file
a1|b1|c1
|b2|c2
a3||c3
a4|b4|
$ egrep "^\||\|\||\|$" file
|b2|c2
a3||c3
a4|b4|
```